# How to specity workspace clean for hosted agents in Azure DevOps build pipeline for Pipeline with steps and one implicit job?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build-pipeline

I am trying to clean the DevOps workspace as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipelinesteps) (Pipeline with Steps and one implicit job)

From what I see, I should add a `workspace:` row in the YAML, but when I follow the instruction I get an error saying

`Unexpected value 'workspace'`

The relative pipeline snippet is the following:

```
pool:
  name: 'Hosted Agents'

workspace:
  clean: all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differently from what showed in Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipelinesteps) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines) , the only way to make this work is adding the `workspace` element at the same level of the `name` within the `pool`:

```
pool:
  name: 'Hosted Agents'
  workspace:
    clean: all
```

And not at the same level of `pool`